# Dynamically created iframe doesn't fire load function

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a button that should download a file on click.

I use the following code in my onclick funcion:

```
var ifr=$('<iframe/>', {
    id:'MainPopupIframe',
    src:'https://myasp?downloadfile',
    style:'display:none;width:320px;height:400px',
    load:function(){
        $(this).show();
        alert('File downloaded !');
    }
});

$('body').append(ifr);
```

For some reason the load function is never triggered. If I use normal URL like https://stackoverflow.com/ it works like a charm, but it doesn't with my asp.

So what is the difference and what do I do wrong?

Comment: if it's a forced download then no page change occurs and iframe never does load a page

Comment: @charlietfl so do you have any idea how to fix that? I'm not sure what do you mean by forced download, but yeah - the file downloads immediately on click.

Comment: what is the point? Browsers have download progress built in

Comment: Because I need to hide a certain css when my download finishes. I just need the load function to works .. but it doesn't with this asp link.

Comment: Then perhaps you should use an ajax download